# Auto fill field with value from above row value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row

I would like to auto fill empty values with the above value.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
      Nr,
      [Name]
FROM #TEMP
```

**Table**:

[image]

**I want my output to look like this**:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to use subquery:

```
SELECT t1.Nr, Name = (SELECT TOP 1 Name 
                      FROM #temp t2 
                      WHERE Name IS NOT NULL 
                        AND t1.Nr >= t2.Nr
                      ORDER BY Nr DESC)
FROM #temp t1
ORDER BY Nr;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/405415)**</kbd>

or `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t1.Nr, sub.Name
FROM #temp t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Name 
             FROM #temp t2 
             WHERE Name IS NOT NULL 
               AND t1.Nr >= t2.Nr
             ORDER BY Nr DESC) AS sub
ORDER BY Nr;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/405418)**</kbd>

Comment: How would you do if you have 5 columns that needed auto fill?, i do not want to make a sub query for all 5 fields.

Comment: @Nils This is not how SO works. I answered your initial question and you marked it as answer. Now you unmarked my answer and add new conditions. If you need futher help ask new question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions You should also prepare sample data with 5 blank column to fill + http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: You are right i have marked your answer and will ask another question if so needed thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The general consensus seems to be that this is not something that databases are meant to do, or should be doing (if it can be avoided). [See here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost1383708.aspx).

That being said, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465847/sql-how-to-fill-empty-cells-with-previous-row-value) seems to be trying to do the same thing as yours and has a few valid solutions.

Comment: You are probably right that this should not be done in a database but telling the user to manually put in the same value is much harder.

Comment: I agree. The second link in my post might have a useful solution. If this is a one-time action, you could also export your dataset to Excel and generate a series of queries with a formula and just execute them line-by-line to bring the table up to date. I find that's often faster to write when this is the case.