# When a table value is 0, how can I make it select the nearest above value that isn't 0?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops

In SQL 2008, I'm looking for a way to convert all the 0s to the nearest value above that isn't 0. Basically, I want this:

```
+--------+-------+
| Number | Cost  |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | 5.84  |
|      2 | 0.00  |
|      3 | 0.00  |
|      4 | 0.00  |
|      5 | 0.00  |
|      6 | 5.98  |
|      7 | 0.00  |
|      8 | 0.00  |
+--------+-------+
```

To Look like this:

```
+--------+-------+
| Number | Cost  |
+--------+-------+
|      1 | 5.84  |
|      2 | 5.84  |
|      3 | 5.84  |
|      4 | 5.84  |
|      5 | 5.84  |
|      6 | 5.98  |
|      7 | 5.98  |
|      8 | 5.98  |
+--------+-------+
```

The problem is, a loop is super taxing as I have to do this on thousands of values. Here's the loop I tried:

```
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #table  WHERE cost is null) > 0

    BEGIN

        UPDATE TOP (1) #table
        SET cost = ((select cost from #table t2 where (f2.number = #table.number + 1)))
        WHERE cost = 0

    END
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: You are way better off pulling the data set first, then working with the result set.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: It's hard to say because we lack context, but it looks like a deeply flawed schema design, where you ought to have (at least) an additional column in that table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: How to fill empty cells with previous row value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465847/sql-how-to-fill-empty-cells-with-previous-row-value)

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #numbers (number INT, cost DECIMAL(10, 3))

INSERT INTO #numbers
        (number, cost)
VALUES  
(      1 , 5.84  ),
(      2 , 0.00  ),
(      3 , 0.00  ),
(      4 , 0.00  ),
(      5 , 0.00  ),
(      6 , 5.98  ),
(      7 , 0.00  ),
(      8 , 0.00  )



UPDATE #numbers 
SET cost = (SELECT TOP 1 m.cost FROM #numbers m  WHERE cost > 0 AND n.number > m.number
    ORDER BY m.number desc
)
FROM #numbers n
WHERE cost = 0

SELECT * FROM #numbers


DROP TABLE #numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

```
update #table set cost = (
    select top 1 cost
    from #table t2
    where t2.number < #table.number
    and t2.cost <> 0
    order by number desc
)
where cost = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table name is table1, Try this query:

```
update table1 set Cost = 
    case when Cost <> 0 then Cost
    else (select top 1 Cost from table1 t2 
      where t2.Cost <> 0 and t2.Number < table1.Number 
      order by table1.Number desc)
    end
from table1
```