# BigQuery: need a clever solution for a difficult query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The context of this problem is a Live Chat service. Each *conversation* consists of multiple *messages* of which the *timestamp* is registred. Conversations are held in one or more *channels*, depending on the difficulty of the inquiry.

The picture below shows an example of the data. For testing purposes the sheet can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NMOJ-9gykb7HpeEsJcOIxv2pUsizyU5aZHzbM_dbUH0/edit?usp=sharing).

[image]

In the picture you see the initial difficulty is determined at row 5 (based on the content of the messages). Rows 2 till 4 should have the same difficulty, as these messages form a group. After that it gets easier, as all messages between two difficulties belong to the one earlier in time (basically messages are of difficulty X until difficulty Y is introduced). The colors in the picture show which difficulty should belong to which messages.

So far I have succeeded in writing a query which can assign the correct difficulty to rows 5 till 29. Using the same logic and a subquery, I could probably also find a way to assign the correct difficulty to messages before the first channel ID, but **I was wondering of any of you see a cleaner, more intuitive way to solve this.**

```
WITH channelMessage AS (
SELECT conversation, channel, timestamp
FROM MessagesTable
WHERE channel IS NOT NULL
AND channel != '' 
),

messages AS (
SELECT a.message, b.channel, a.conversation, a.timestamp,
CASE WHEN b.timestamp IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TIMESTAMP_DIFF(b.timestamp, a.timestamp, MILLISECOND) END AS diff,
CASE WHEN b.timestamp IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MAX(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(b.timestamp, a.timestamp, MILLISECOND)) OVER (PARTITION BY a.message ORDER BY a.timestamp) END AS diff2
FROM MessagesTable AS a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM channelMessage) AS b
ON a.conversation = b.conversation AND a.timestamp >= b.timestamp
)

SELECT timestamp, conversation, message, channel, diff, diff2,
FROM messages 
WHERE diff = diff2
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The channel for each message that doesn't already have one is the channel of the most recent earlier message in the same conversation that does have a channel. To handle rows 2-4 we can say that if there is no earlier message with a channel, we'll take the earliest message in the conversation that does have a channel.

I've renamed your table to "Messages" for clarity.

```
SELECT a.timestamp, a.conversation, 
  COALESCE(
    -- Message already has a channel
    a.channel,
    -- Channel from most recent earlier message
    (SELECT MAX(c.channel) FROM Messages c
         WHERE c.conversation = a.conversation
         AND c.timestamp =
           (SELECT MAX(c2.timestamp) FROM Messages c2
                WHERE c2.conversation = a.conversation
                AND c2.channel IS NOT NULL
                AND c2.timestamp < a.timestamp)),
    -- Channel of earliest message
    (SELECT MAX(c.channel) FROM Messages c
         WHERE c.conversation = a.conversation
         AND c.timestamp =
           (SELECT MIN(c2.timestamp) FROM Messages c2
                WHERE c2.conversation = a.conversation
                AND c2.channel IS NOT NULL))) AS channel
FROM Messages a;
```

There's another solution that involves assigning a number to each row of the original table, then [using a recursive CTE to find the previous non-NULL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465847/sql-how-to-fill-empty-cells-with-previous-row-value). You'd need to figure out how to handle rows 2-4 in this case. I think my solution is a more straightforward implementation of the channel selection logic you described.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I like your idea and the use of COALESCE function (which I did not know about). However, when I try to use the code, all messages are assigned to the easyQuestions channel, with exception of the messages that already have a channel. 

My gut feeling says the second column of the COALESCE statement has an error, but I do not completely understand the logic behind it either.

Comment: I think `c2.timestamp < c.timestamp` should be `c2.timestamp < a.timestamp`!

Comment: The inequality in ```c2.timestamp < a.timestamp``` produces an error (LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.). I will try to figure it out and post my findings. Thank you for your time and suggested idea :)

Comment: I'll take another look, this is a pretty standard SQL idiom, maybe I forgot something.

Comment: Update again to remove the CTE. This works in MySQL. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e0819/1

Comment: I think you proved that your solution works. However, BigQuery does not seem to like the comparisons between a2 and c (Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.). Maybe I can alter the query in such a way that the error message does not occur.